# How to position an element to center inside of a grid column?

Tags: visualforce, css, lightning-design-system, slds

On my VF page I'd like to center a content of a grid column.

Code:

```
<apex:page>
    <head>
        <apex:slds />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-8 slds-box"></div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-box">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" type="button">
                    Click Me
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-box"></div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-box">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" type="button">
                    Click Me
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-8 slds-box"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

How does it look like:

[image]

How I want it to look like:

[image]

I thought an `slds-grid_align-center` style would do the trick but sadly does not. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`slds-grid_align-center` is used to position the grid cells from the center of the grid box. It does not center the content of those grid cells. In your case, what you're looking for is `slds-align_absolute-center`:

```
<apex:page>
    <head>
        <apex:slds />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-8 slds-box"></div>
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-box">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" type="button">
                    Click Me
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-box"></div>
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-box">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" type="button">
                    Click Me
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-8 slds-box"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

[image: slds-align_absolute-center]